# High power heating element control

Tags: microcontroller, power, control, scr

How to control high power (~5kW) heating element using MCU? I need a very simple application that shuts down the element, when it reaches set temperature. Maybe I can do it using SCR? F.e. Т161-160 (https://www.pentod.com/userfiles/product_files_shared/T161-160.pdf). And what should I pay attention to?

Comment: How accurately do you need to control the temperature? A simple On-Off controller will not regulate very well. If you need precise temperature control, you need a PID controller. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller

Answer (score 1):

Use a solid-state relay (SSR). It provides complete electrical isolation between your controller and the mains by means of optical isolation.